# Dynamics CRM - Caller not authenticated to service

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an MVC4 Web Application on Web Server A that is consuming the Dynamics CRM Web Service using the OrganizationServiceProxy, which is on Web Server B.  The MVC4 application is setup with ASP .NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication enabled.  When I call the WhoAmI I get an error:

'The caller was not authenticated by the service.'

Now if I move the MVC4 Application to Web Server B (same as CRM) with the same Authentication as it had on Web Server A it calls WhoAmI without an exception.

Here is the code being used to connect to the server.

```
        string serviceURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMROOTURL"].ToString() + "XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";

        this.CRMService = GetCRMService(serviceURL);

private OrganizationServiceProxy GetCRMService(string serviceURL)
{
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        OrganizationServiceProxy client
            = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(serviceURL), null, credentials, null);

        return client;
 }
```

Here is a screenshot of the authentication on the IIS Web Site.

[image]

Per the correct answer I just wanted to provide some snippets to help anyone else.

```
string loggedUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

OrganizationServiceProxy client
    = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(serviceURL), null, credentials, null);

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials.Windows.ClientCredential;

// -- Retrieve the user.
QueryExpression expression = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "systemuser",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("systemuserid")
};

expression.Criteria.AddCondition("domainname", ConditionOperator.Equal, loggedUser);

EntityCollection ec = client.RetrieveMultiple(expression);

if (ec.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    // -- Impersonate the logged in user.
    client.CallerId = ec.Entities[0].Id;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Application Identity of the Application Pool that hosts the MVC4 Web Application different between the two servers?

Comment: They are currently different from one another.  Should I make them the same and try that?

Comment: `GetCRMService` really isn't helpful.  I need to see the code where the constructor of the OrganizationServiceProxy is called, and more importantly, what credentials you're passing to it, and how the credentials are getting instantiated.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the function to the post.

Comment: It's very important that you don't use the same OrganizationServiceProxy object if you use it before you set the CallerId. The callerid is cached and your calls will fail. Once you have the guid of the user you want to impersonate you need to create a new OrganizationServiceProxy object and set the CallerId of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you explicitly state otherwise (and without any code to see how you are creating your OrganizationServiceProxy), on premise OrganizationServiceProxies will use the current AD account (of the service account, not the user's specific account) to connect to CRM.  I'm guessing that the App pool you're running on Server A isn't a CRM user, and the one on Server B is.  If so, either change Server A's user to be the same user as Server B, or make the Server A's user a user in CRM.

### Edit

You're using the default network credentials to connect to CRM.  This mean that no matter what IIS authentication you are using, you will connect to CRM as the App Pool User Account.  This works as long as the App Pool user is a CRM user, but is probably not what you want.

You can set the network credential manually using this method:

```
creds.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserId", "Password", "DomainName");
```

Then get the ASP.Net User's domain name and use impersonation to connect to CRM to ensure that all of the security for that individual is correctly applied.

Comment: I added the code snippet and a screenshot of the authentication in IIS.  The error feels like it could be a Kerbos 'Double Hop' issue, but I am unsure of needed SPN's, etc. to resolve it, if that's the issue.

Comment: That makes sense, my only question just so I fully understand this, is why does it work if i put the MVC4 site on the same server as the CRM website?  The IIS settings are exactly the same as I have on the remote server, but it works and authenticates with the logged in windows user (to the site) with no issues when on the same server as CRM.

Comment: @widmayer You mentioned that the User of the App pool was different in IIS between servers.  Is this not the case?

Comment: That approach worked.  The App Pool User is different between the servers, I am going to test if they are the same to see if it the results differ, but I also like the approach using an explicit login, I feel like it gives more control.

Answer (score 0):

Something stupid - be careful you aren't escaping your user name!

```
creds.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("domain\user", "PASSWORD");
```

Notice that the \u is an escape sequence - you need to type "domain\user".