# MSCRM 2013 - The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: web-services, wcf, authentication, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to call CRM webservice from my custom WCF service. And I am getting the exception "The caller was not authenticated by the service". Checked the authentication mode in IIS (where my wcf service is hosted). Its set to anonymous authentication enabled.

Is there any reason why MSCRM service would fail authentication while call is made from WCF?

Here is my code which calls the CRM web service

```
 OrganizationService service; 
 var crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Server=http://myserver/orgname; Domain=domainname; Username=username; Password=passwordtext");
 service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);
 Entity crmEvent = service.Retrieve("new_event", eventId, new ColumnSet("status"));
```

Comment: How are you trying to call the web service? Can you update your question with some code? Are you using developer extensions to invoke the connection, most of the work is done by under the hood for you when you use these methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695819(v=crm.7).aspx

Comment: Can you also post crmConnection object initialization? And your config settings? If you are using config file for your connection string elements, does it look something like so ?   <add name="CRM" connectionString="Server=http://contoso.com; Domain=contoso; Username=username; Password=password"/>, so you can use var crmConnection = new CrmConnection("CRM");

Comment: Your connection looks good, things I would check are trivial things like, escaping domain name properly (@"contoso\admin"), double checking the password etc.

Answer (score 0):

When using windows authentication you need to pass a Networkcredential to the constructor of the OrganizationService.

This was already answered by @Daryl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663777/dynamics-crm-caller-not-authenticated-to-service/18664941#18664941).